# Best use of Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

i'm having some difficulties understanding Enum in java.

Let's say i have an enum

```
public enum EnumTest {

    TEST1("Test1"),
    TEST2("Test2"),
    TEST3("Test3"),
    TEST4("Test4");

    private final String NAME;

    EnumTest (String n) {
        NAME=n;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return NAME;
    }
}
```

and a client

```
public class Client {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        for (EnumTest vet:EnumTest.values()){       
            System.out.println(vet);
        }

        String vett1=EnumTest.TEST1.getName();              
        EnumTest vett2=EnumTest.TEST2;

        System.out.println(vett1);
        System.out.println(vett2);
    }
}
```

which one has the correct declaration?

vett1 seems quite ... "ugly" to me, but has the best output format;
vett2 seems cleaner, but i don't know why i'm not satisfied.

Are there good habits of declaration?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why are you not satisfied with vett2?

Comment: You might want to read up on what enums are and how they are used. What you're asking about is how enums are represented as strings and in that case both options are ok, it all depends on what you need.

Comment: vett1 is the name, vett2 is the enum instance itself.

Comment: What you are calling "declaration" is actually just the representation of the enum. And here there is no best. You choose whatever fits best to your needs.

Comment: You shouldnt use all uppercase for a field name. It is not a real CONSTANT; thus "name" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change

```
public String getName() {
    return NAME;
}
```

to

```
public String toString() {
    return NAME;
}
```

you will get the output of vett1 but you can use it without explicit calling getName().

This is because java calls toString() to convert the enum member to a string it can print out.
But if you do not define the toString() method yourself it will call toString on the enums supercalss.

Answer (score 2):

Write a new method toString() to return Name variable on EnumTest class

```
public String toString() {
    return NAME;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to achieve. In your code example you implemented a method called getName that returns the private variable NAME from the enum. This is the value of vett1. The value that is printed when printing vett2 on is the same value that you would get by calling toStirng() on the enum value. In this your example the case of the two values are different, but implementing methods in an enumeration can do much more than simply return a name. It can return any data type. So it really depends what you want to do.